# When exporting my Java Project, It won't export my Assets

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, packaging

I am trying to export my java project to an executable file (a .jar) but it wont bring along the assets with it(such as pictures and things). I am programming with Eclipse. I have looked at other forums about this and try their fixes but it doesn't seem to work for me. I think the problem has something to do with where i put my .gif and .wav. I put them in the same folder as the src folder with my .java files. Here is my code. Thanks for the help!

```
class ImagePaneTest extends JFrame  
{  
  ImageIcon ic = new   ImageIcon("scary.gif");  
  JDesktopPane dp = new JDesktopPane();  
  JLabel lbl = new JLabel(ic);  
  JPanel transparentPanel = new JPanel();  

  public ImagePaneTest()  
   {  

      lbl.setBounds(0, 0, 553, 421);   

      dp.add(lbl,new Integer(50));  
      dp.add(transparentPanel,new Integer(350));  

      setLayeredPane(dp);  

   }  
   public static void main(String a[])  
   {  

       try {
            Thread.sleep(8000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

       ImagePaneTest fr = new ImagePaneTest();  
       Image icon = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);
       fr.setIconImage(icon);

       fr.setSize(553,421);   
       fr.setVisible(true);
       fr.toFront();
       fr.setLocation(370, 200);

       sound play = new sound();
       play.playSound("wail.wav");
       System.exit(0);
   }  

}
```

Comment: What does exporting your assets have to do with your code?

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that you guys had everything you need to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify it from . (dot)

Let's suppose this class

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class ImagePaneTest extends JFrame
{
    ImageIcon       ic                  = new ImageIcon("./images/nice.jpg");
    JDesktopPane    dp                  = new JDesktopPane();
    JLabel          lbl                 = new JLabel(ic);
    JPanel          transparentPanel    = new JPanel();

    public ImagePaneTest()
    {

        lbl.setBounds(0, 0, 553, 421);

        dp.add(lbl, new Integer(50));
        dp.add(transparentPanel, new Integer(350));

        setLayeredPane(dp);

    }

    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        ImagePaneTest fr = new ImagePaneTest();
        Image icon = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);
        fr.setIconImage(icon);

        fr.setSize(553, 421);
        fr.setVisible(true);
        fr.toFront();
        fr.setLocation(370, 200);
    }

}
```

[image]

then you export to jar (not runnable jar) using the default options, except for the main class

[image]

then

```
java -jar my.jar
```

and voilà

[image]

Comment: Tried this but still did not work. Where do you think my resources should be? In the src folder or in the project folder with everything else?

Comment: ok I tried your new edited solution. Thanks for the help. I am understanding the whole exporting process alot more now, but I did not understand what you wanted me to do with the **java -jar my.jar** part. I tried everything else you said except for that, and it didn't work.

Comment: I've exported as a jar called my.jar and since ImagePaneTest was set as the Main Class (see the screenshot #2), java -jar my.jar will execute the jar you've exported from that class. And since the generated jar contains a directory called "images" with the image inside, then your image is encapsulated inside the jar and you can distribute the jar.

Comment: are you using the dot before the file path name?

Comment: Yes, and after that change, it still works in eclipse, but when i export it and run the .jar the window comes up but without a picture and then quits quickly, because the music doesn't work either.

Comment: Alright, so I found out something that might help. I opened up the .jar folder after exporting it with winRar and found that there was no images folder in there(The folder that holds the resources just like you used). So I added an images folder with the resources inside and it still didn't work. But when I left an images folder with the resources on the desktop it worked. So I think there is a problem with how I access the resources in the code, that makes it different in another environment. What does the . (dot) operator actually do in the path?

Comment: all your files are in a relative path from the eclipse project root. For example, my project is called "sand" and it has a directory called "images". Let's suppose we decided to store the images under "images/xyz". Then, when we export the jar (adding all the resource directories, of course), we must tell the java interpreter that images are under "./images/xyz". DOT is the root of your jar.

Comment: That makes since, but it doesn't make since how in my situation it seems like it needs the images to be on the desktop, Because otherwise it won't work.

Comment: what's your app path and what's your resources path in your machine?

Comment: Documents/eclipse/myproject.  For machine and ./images/"mypic" for the app

Answer (score 0):

Put the resources in `src`, or if you're using Maven, `src/main/resources`.

Comment: My resources are in src and I'm not using Maven

Comment: Actually my resources are not in src. They are just in the project folder with the src and bin folders. So I tried putting the resources in the src folder, but then the resources did not show when the program ran.